# Which easy programming language to use for parallel port programming under Linux?

Tags: linux, programming-languages, ubuntu, hardware, parallel-port

My father would like to use Ubuntu for LPT programming (via a relay card). He is used to QBasic and PowerBasic but willing to learn a new (simple) language for his goals.

What recommendations can you give me for this task?

**Python** would be my favourite if the module [pyParallel](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyparallel.html) worked. If there are other modules available for Python, let me know.

I cannot change the hardware, it's a requirement to only change software.

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python module pyParallel works. I had tried the release last time. Yesterday I used the HEAD revision and it works.

For somebody trying to do the same procedure:

1. Download & install the HEAD revision of pyParallel.
2. Unload the kernel module `lp` and load `ppdev`. It lets you access the parallel port device file.
3. a) Add your OS user to the group `lp` so it has write access to `/dev/parport*`.
   b) Otherwise execute this: `# chmod a+rw /dev/parport*`
4. Hack your program!

<strike>Steps 2., 3. b) and 4. must repeated every reboot. The blacklisting does not work properly (yet).

You can create a `udev` rule for the parport device file so that every user has write access to it.</strike>
**Update:** The blacklist now works. It was a bug in Ubuntu 9.04 with CUPS. In 9.10 it works perfectly.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mono-project.com/Visual_Basic He'll at least be familiar with the language, but accessing the parallel port is a more complicated task.  I know there is a way, but all the samples online deal with windows libraries.

Comment: Of course QBasic (on dos) doesn't have a memory protected operating system running above it either.

Answer (score 1):

The Python is not easier than Basic. But I think for parallel port and other hardware programming C is a natural choice. It's not that hard to learn and it's worth to spend some time learning C.

Comment: It's fairly easy to learn C, but it's harder to learn how to program well in it.  I'd suggest that people learn C either because they need it, or as part of getting deeper knowledge of computers and computation.

Comment: C would be a nice solution, but I think it's too hard to achieve little tasks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/), it has it's own IDE and can interface with tons of languages as well as run on all platforms. It's more of a hobbyists thing but might work out for you.

Comment: The hardware must be LPT. Only software may change.